# How to generate hexagonal patterns on the largest faces of a cuboid?

Tags: modeling, python, mesh, 3d-view

I'm new to blender and I want to generate a cuboid with certain dimensions (250 x 120 x 34), and then create a 3D hexagonal grid with depth only on both of its largest faces. The hexagonal grid should be double-sided, with each outer hexagon in the grid having a side of 2 cm, and the distance between the outer hexagon's sides and the inner hexagon's sides is 3 millimeters long. The depth of the wedge between these 2 hexagons should be 29 millimeters. Something like this pattern with depth but on a cuboid with the mentioned dimensions and modeled as if the inner hexagons are filled instead of the wedges in between:

[image: The Pattern]

So far I have written this code to generate this via python, but it doesn't generate anything but the cuboid, and it's not the correct pattern at all. How can I generate what I need?

```
import bpy

# Create a new cuboid
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=1, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0))

# Set cuboid dimensions
bpy.context.object.scale = (2.5, 1.2, 0.34)

# Enter edit mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

# Select the largest faces
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_face_by_sides(number=4, type='GREATER')

# Create a hexagon
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(vertices=6, radius=0.02, depth=0.029, location=(0,0,0))

# Scale the hexagon to 2D
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(1, 1, 0))

# Duplicate the hexagon to create a grid
bpy.ops.mesh.duplicate_move()
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(2.5,1.2,1))

# Extrude the hexagons along the Z axis
bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, 0.029)})

# To make the hexagonal grid double-sided
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.context.object.data.use_auto_smooth = True
```

Comment: Hello, I'm doubtful a human wrote this piece of code, it doesn't really make sense. You can adjust the output of the algorithm you used to create this by telling it what went wrong, but I would scrap it altogether and begin anew. Could you add a diagram or example describing the final pattern in 3D ?

Comment: @Gorgious It doesn't generate anything but a cuboid. As I said I don't know how to use python with Blender so it was just trial and error by reading tutorials

Comment: No, three hexagons are already generated. They are not visible because they are inside the cube. Press Z > Wireframe.